# Bad Gateway issue with PHP API

Tags: php, mysql, api

Hey I made an API in PHP from my MySQL database, It is rather CPU intensive and is being called multiple times a second.

```
$timer = $candle_time * 60;

$DATABASE_HOST = '';
$DATABASE_USER = '';                       
$DATABASE_PASS = '';
$DATABASE_NAME = '';

$response = array();

$link = mysqli_connect($DATABASE_HOST, $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS, $DATABASE_NAME);
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE 'name' ORDER BY table.datetime ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    $dates .= $row[1]. ',';
    $price .= $row[2]. ","; 
    $datetime .= $row[3]. ',';
}
$dates = explode(",",$dates);
$price = explode(",",$price);
$datetime = explode(",",$datetime); 

for($i = 0; $i < count($dates); $i++){
    array_push($response,array(strtotime($datetime[$i]),$dates[$i],$price[$i]));
}

$counting_segments = 0;
$grouped_prices = array();
$final_grouping = array();

$rounded = ceil($response[0][0]/$timer)*$timer;
$counted = count($response)-1;

for($i = 0; $i < count($response); $i++){
    if($i == $counted){
        $rounded = ceil($previous_time/$timer)*$timer;
        array_push($final_grouping,array($rounded,$grouped_prices));
    }    
    if($response[$i][0] > $rounded){
        $previous_time = $response[$i][0];
        array_push($final_grouping,array($rounded,$grouped_prices));
        $grouped_prices = array();
        $rounded = ceil($response[$i][0]/$timer)*$timer;
    }
    if($response[$i][0] < $rounded){
        $previous_time = $response[$i][0];
        array_push($grouped_prices,$response[$i][2]);  
    } else {
        array_push($grouped_prices,$response[$i][2]);    
    }
}

$new_array = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($final_grouping); $i++){
    $first_array = $final_grouping[$i][0];
    $second_array = $final_grouping[$i][1];

    $first_price = $second_array[0];
    $last_price = end($second_array);
    $high_price = max($second_array);
    $low_price = min($second_array);
    $final_date = $first_array;
    $obj = new StdClass;
    $obj->time = $final_date;
    $obj->open = $first_price;
    $obj->high = $high_price;
    $obj->low = $low_price;
    $obj->close = $last_price;
    array_push($new_array,$obj);
}
$json_api = json_encode($new_array);
echo $json_api
```

I think the reason for the 503 is the CPU power it is taking to calculate the requests. Is there a way I can have a script or something that pulls the data and saves it to a php file every second to lessen the load or is there a better way of doing this?

I did run this personally and it works perfectly, however with more people requesting from it it provides a 503 often.

Thanks.

Comment: The most CPU expensive is MySQL query. Try to optimize it or just add the limit

Comment: Aside from some fairly inefficient PHP code, you're retrieving a lot of data from the data base which you then iterate over looking for first, last minimum and maximum prices. A more focused query could pull that data directly and save a lot of this effort.

Comment: Can you add your database structure in question as well? it'll make it easier for viewers to find a solution for you

Answer (score 0):

The PHP code itself doesn't look like it should overload the CPU. However, there are a lot of things you can do to optimize it

1. How's the query performing. Execute the query directly and see if you need to add an index. This could be an index on 2 fields: `name` and `datetime`.
2. You're using specific columns `date`, `price`, and `datetime`, but you're getting all rows in the response. It's better to specify the columns you want

   ```
   SELECT `date`, `price`, `datetime` FROM table WHERE name LIKE 'name' ORDER BY table.datetime ASC
   ```
3. You're building up comma-separated strings and then splitting them right after. That's unnecessary. Instead build-up arrays.

   ```
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
       $dates[] = $row[1];
       $price[] = $row[2]; 
       $datetime[] = $row[3];
   }
   ```
4. In this case, you don't even need separate arrays, but can just build-up `$response` in the fetch loop.

   ```
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
       $response[] = array(strtotime($row[1]), $row[2], $row[3]);
   }
   ```

   P.S. Don't use `array_push()` unless you care about the inserted index. The `$array[] = $value` syntax is faster.
5. Just count once, not every iteration in the loop

   ```
   $counted = count($response);

   for($i = 0; $i < $counted; $i++){
       if($i == $counted - 1){
   ```

Comment: This could be a perfect simplified example, @tonni89marsent try this and it'll reduce your data processing time